# window manager bad token unable to add window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am opening a dialog in adapter class. but its shows me error of window manager bad token..

```
private void Dialog()
{

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this.context.getApplicationContext());
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pg_dialog);

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_statusMsg);
    TextView textDescp = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_discriptMsg);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOkDialog);

    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(context, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FetchWalletBalance();


        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and also the adapter class

Answer (score 0):

No use aplicationContext when init Dialog or view, you need change to activity context: Example

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Dialog(this@MainActivity));
```

And change `dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`
To 
`dialog.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST)` or remove this, If not will crash app.